# Google Cloud Natural Language API failed to resolve in Android

Tags: android, api, nlp

I tried to add the API as a dependency but it didn't work. It just gives me this error:

`Failed to resolve: com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:0.20.1-alpha`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:0.21.1-beta'
```

At any time you can go to https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter and search using :

```
 com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language
```

for the current versions available